# Read Microchip hexfile

Tags: pic, microchip

I have inherited a hex file for a PIC design, which contains the programming for a USB device. Is there a way I can open it in order to find out exactly what it means and how it works? i.e. something beyond the raw hexadecimal digits.

Complete beginner here - is there a documentation manual? Is PIC a language of its own?
This shows the 'Code' section is usually the first item: https://www.kanda.com/blog/microcontrollers/pic-microcontrollers/pic-hex-file-format/. Is the Code section human-readable?

Here are the first few lines of one of the hex files:

```
:020000040000FA
:06000000D8EF17F012001A
:020006001200E6
:0600080025EF14F01200C8
:02000E000004EC
:02001000FFFFF0
:0400120000000000EA
:0600180070EF14F012006D
:02001E000500DB
:1000200073300000DC000000210000001F300000E1
:100030006000000054000000120000001E050000D7
:10004000040000000C30000000000000130000005D
:0C0050000E00000035000000040000005D
:04005C000F0E9212DF
:10006000070E9412968093680150030B136E010ED5
:10007000135204E0E846FE0B1306FCE1E81C0F0BEC
:100080008C6E956A841C010B800DF3CF14F0821CDA
:10009000070B100DF3CF13F0801C0F0B131014106F
:1000A000126E12380F0B070B100DF3CFDCF0020E9F
:1000B000E66E4EEC17F0E552086E08500F0802E2AB
:1000C0000F0E086E0950085C02E20950086EFDEC44
:1000D0000AF00F0E1214010F156E0A0E166E16C0DE
:1000E00031F015C02CF0E6EC17F02C50136E146AAA
:1000F000135000019213145093130F0E1214010F9A
```

Comment: The HEX file format was actually invented by Intel and are sometimes called Intel HEX file format (though most people just call it the hex file even though there used to be other incompatible formats of hex files). You can find a fairly good description in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX

Comment: As for the contents of the hex file, you need to know which CPU this program is for. Then you can download the datasheet for the CPU and find out the instruction encoding

Comment: For example, if the CPU is a PIC18F2682 then download the datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39761b.pdf and go to page 368 to find how the instructions are encoded. You then need to decode the instructions in the hex file into PIC18 assembly. Note that there are several different families of PICs so you need to download the correct datasheet - you need to know what CPU this program was written for

Comment: This is not a task for a beginner, you are basically asked to disassemble a program into assembly language - that's kind of like someone giving you Microsoft Word and wants you to create its source code. But it is doable as a beginner. I did this once a long time ago (20 years or so) at the beginning of my career as a freelance job. The code I got was much longer than this so I ended up writing my own simple disassembler to roughly generate the assembly then studied the assembly to insert comments as necessary

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try and find which CPU is being used.

Comment: I do have access to an old computer, suppose I was to search for the source code for the hex file, what would be the file extensions to look for?

Comment: Do you know if it was 8, 16 or 32-bit?  If it is a C file then it will end with .c.  If it is in assembler, then possibly .asm

Answer (score 1):

Actually the default hex format in **MPLAB X IDE** is `Microchip INHX32 HEX-record Format`
more about: https://www.lucidtechnologies.info/inhx32.htm. You can change the file format under project settings.

However there is possibility to invoke `Microchip *.hex` file into **MPLAB X IDE**. This tutorial is valid for **MPLAB X IDE v5.35**.

1)Select from main menu `File/Import/Hex`

2)Press `Browse` button and select desired `*.hex` file.

3)Select debugger tool like `Simulator` and press `Next` button.

4)Press `Finish` button.

5)In Projects tree you will find new `Project` with the same name like imported hex file.

6)Press with the right mouse button on project name and select `Set as main project`

7)Select from main menu `Production` and select `Set Configurations Bits`

8)New Tab named "Configurations Bits" is opened. Under the bottom of window press to `Memory` and select `Program memory` and set `Format` to `Code`!

9)Now you are able to see disassembled code, like:

[image]